# Parse xls file in email

Tags: excel, 64-bit, ms-office, oledb

I am trying to parse an excel file from an email without using an oledb driver or mssql! The client i am working with is using server 2003 x64 and ms sql express 2005. I cannot run IIS in x86 because this would break the exchange owa. I also cannot create a sql job to take in the xls file and spit out a csv because it is an express edition. I am looking for another creative way to accomplish this task without creating any extra costs to the client. Any ideas appreciated looking for a C# or VB method to tackle this issue.

Comment: Any issues using oledb driver?

Comment: running server2003 x64 with IIS in x64 mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Koogra](http://koogra.sourceforge.net/).